# Formulário em Lista UL Li

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário onde a estrutura é formada por uma lista organizada

```
<ul>
    <li id="pai">
        <input type="text"><button class="ul-appending">Add Input</button>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="text"><button class="ul-appending">Add Input</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Os campos são adicionados dinamicamente seguindo a estrutura de listagem.
Porem gostaria de ao final quando o formulário for enviado, seguir essa ordem de listagens com os resultados em uma textarea.
Seria possível?

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button.ul-appending', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('li');
    var childUl = parent.children('ul');
    if(childUl.length === 0) {
        parent.append("<ul class='newul'></ul>");
        childUl = parent.children('ul');       
    }
    childUl.append($("<li><input type='text'><span></span><button class='ul-appending'>add</button></li>"));
});
```

```css
*{padding: 0; border: 0;  outline: 0; list-style-type: none;  font-weight: inherit;   font-style: inherit;    vertical-align: baseline;   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    box-sizing: border-box;}


.organograma input[type='text'] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius:  3px;
    margin-bottom:  10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #555;
    display: inline-block;
}

.organograma button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #888;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0!important;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.organograma ul {
    padding-left:  15px;
    position: relative;
}

.organograma ul:before {
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    height: calc(100% - 17px);
    background: #bbb;
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
    top: -10px;
}

.organograma ul:after {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #bbb;
    position: absolute;
    left: -8px;
    bottom: 27px;
}

.organograma > ul:after, .organograma > ul > li > ul:after {
    content: none;
}


.organograma > ul:before {
    content: none;
}

.organograma ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.organograma ul li:before {
    content: "";
    width: 9px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #bbb;
    position: absolute;
    left: -8px;
    top: 17px;
}

.organograma > ul > li:before {
    content: none;
}

.organograma ul li:last-child {
    margin-bottom:  0;
}

.organograma > ul {
    padding-left:  0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="organograma">
    <ul>
        <li id="pai">
            <input type="text" value="Prefeito"><span></span><button class="ul-appending">add</button>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="text"><span></span><button class="ul-appending">add</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sim, não sei se vai pegar o resultado do form no php mas é só vc pegar todos os results exemplo $result1 =  $_POST['result1'];, $result2 = $_POST['resul2']; e ai na hora de exibir no text area você da um echo na ordem que quer exemplo echo $result1.",".$result2;

Comment: Porem o formulário adiciona campos dinamicamente criando uma ordem com vários ul li ul li ul li... então não dá pra montar manualmente esse resultado. eu pensei que poderia ser feito por javascript, convertendo a lista toda em um valor para uma textarea. porem não sei como montar isso.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem então, no seu jsfiddle você adiciona a palavra e ele vai adicionando tipo um filho né? Mas não entendi oque há de errado e nem oque quer

Comment: A ideia é seguir essa estrutura de lista. que todos os resultados sigam essa listagem que é montada dinamicamente no formulário. juntar todos os resultados num textarea

Comment: Se você quer uma representação desse organograma em texto, dá para fazer sim... mas dá um pouco de trabalho, o ideal seria você primeiro tentar implementar essa funcionalidade e depois retornar com um erro específico a ser corrigido.

Comment: De um exemplo do que deve aparecer no textarea. Seria algo assim: `Prefeito,ValorCampo,ValorDoAdd1,ValorDoAdd2,etcc`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jlnzbc    Será nesse estimo, quero montar um organograma. então o resultado final tem que ser nesse estilo.

Comment: Não estou captando o que queres. Você diz >> `resultados em uma textarea`. Você quer essa estrutura ul li mostrada no prntscr.com dentro de um textarea?

Comment: você quer o html como texto????

Comment: Isso @LeoCaracciolo. quero preencher os campos, adicionar novos campos e no final exportar tudo  como tá no prntscr. creio que seria mais como enviar para o textarea todo conteúdo da listagem, porem excluindo os inputs, e os buttons. deixando a lista limpa só com os textos dentro de cada ul li.

Comment: Huahuahua, pra colocar os dados em um textarea é moleza, agora, com a estrutura pretendida acho que só a galera do Tio Bill.